# Passing Hexadecimal string from URL query string is not working in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I have a simple action `test` on `HomeController` as follows

```
public ActionResult test(string uid)
        {
            return Content(uid);
        }
```

`www.abc.com/home/test?uid=0XABC` throws error on a shared hosting server. but it works on local and other servers as well.

My Application built on ASP MVC, .Net framework 4.7.2, IIS 10

Please help me to find why this is not binding as a string on some servers.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Do you mean other querystring is working well just this hex querystring? I suggest you could also use the [fail request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to troubleshoot this issue. I guess you may enabled the request filtering or other url checking to caused this issue.